# Why isInterrupted() gives other result than Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() (JAVA)

Tags: java, multithreading

I study java threads and can't understand one moment:
In the following code

```
public class ThreadsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        ExtendsThread extendsThread = new ExtendsThread();
        Thread et = new Thread(extendsThread);
        et.start();    
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ir.interrupt();               
    }      
}

public class ExtendsThread extends Thread {
    private Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    public void run() {
        while (!currentThread .isInterrupted()) {}
        System.out.println("ExtendsThread " + currentThread().isInterrupted());

    }
}
```

thread doesn't stop.
But if in ExtendsThread class I check `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` thread stops.
Why `private Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();` doesn't refer to current thread?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Difference in usage between Thread.interrupted() and Thread.isInterrupted()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904072/java-difference-in-usage-between-thread-interrupted-and-thread-isinterrupted)

Comment: does this code compile? what's `ir`?

Comment: @piotrek, `ir` is probably a typo and should be `et`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault... there shoud be "et"...

Comment: Your `ExtendsThread` class is never used as a `Thread` (i.e., you never call its `start()` method).  You are only using it as a `Runnable`.  You might as well write `class ExtendsThread implements Runnable`, except that then, you might also want to change its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why private `Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();` doesn't refer to current thread?

Because at the time of this variable initialization, you're on the main thread. (The variable is initialized when you do `ExtendsThread extendsThread = new ExtendsThread();` and this is done from `main`.)

---

However, there are other issues with the code.

- You're checking the interrupt on `currentThread` and not `this` thread. So start by changing the `ExtendsThread` code to:

  ```
  class ExtendsThread extends Thread {
      public void run() {
          while (!isInterrupted()) {
          }
          System.out.println("ExtendsThread " + isInterrupted());
      }
  }
  ```
- Then you got the inheritance messed up. When you do like this:

  ```
  ExtendsThread extendsThread = new ExtendsThread();
  Thread et = new Thread(extendsThread);
  ```

  Which means that you're wrapping one thread within another. (So when you're interrupting you're interrupting the outer thread, but you're checking for interrupts on the inner thread.) You probably just want to get rid of the wrapping thread, and do

  ```
  ExtendsThread et = new ExtendsThread();
  ```

Here's the full *working* version of your code:

```
public class ThreadsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ExtendsThread et = new ExtendsThread();
        et.start();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        et.interrupt();
    }
}

class ExtendsThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
        }
        System.out.println("ExtendsThread " + isInterrupted());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse `Thread` with thread.  There is no "inner thread."   The code in this example creates two `Thread` _objects_, but it only creates one new thread.  A `Thread` object is created when you call `new Thread(...)`, but the actual thread is not created until the program calls `et.start()`.  The example code does not use the `ExtendsThread` object as a `Thread` (i.e., never calls its `start()` method).  It only uses that object as a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an `ExtendsThread`, you're assigning the thread that called the constructor to `currentThread`. So your `currentThread` isn't actually what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

you should do `Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();` inside `run()`. otherwise currentThread refers to main thread (the thread that constructs an object) but `run` is executed by different thread